# Not using code first migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I love code first. But here and then facing contraint problems and such , that makes me drop database and recreate etc.

My concern is that, once in production, i cant do that.

Is it possible not to use code first migrations and just creating fields by hand at database/tables?

That also makes me worry for foreign key constraints again.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this about "Code First with Existing Db" ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use code-first migrations? They can do exactly what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use EF < 4.3 you can recreate database on dev server and manual update production database in two step:

1. creating fields by hand at tables
2. update **EdmMetadata** table (use data form dev database)

Else use code first migrations : update-database -script, 
This command generate update script for you database, and you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

At about 4:20, the tutorial video at the Microsoft website starts talking about Migrations
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx